# How to get Original route on 404

Tags: model-view-controller, error-handling, routes

I have a custom route for 404 in my application as follows

Inside the About Action, is there a direct way to capture the original route and query string parameters typed by the user.

So far I have found 2 objects which could give the original path but not the query string params.

My origila request route was "test?checking=true"

1. Request.RawUrl has "/Home/About/?aspxerrorpath=/test" from which I can extract the route from aspxErrorPath. But losing the query string params
2. ValueProviderDictionary in the controller base has the original route as the last element. But again no query string params and also this Dictionary object is deemed obsolete.

Comment: My config for 404 custom route got removed on posting. Here is it           error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/About/"

Comment: Anyone?? Is it possible to get the original route and query string parameters for the call that caused an error redirect?